# error: /index.xhtml @30,146 <f:ajax> 'valueChange' is not a supported event for HtmlForm. Please specify one of: click, dblclick, keydown, etc

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have code here that works correctly:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{customer.selectedname}" id="ulist">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{customer.allCustomers}"/>
                        <f:ajax event="change" render="cid fname lname email sd" listener="#{customer.fullInfo}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

But, when I implement it in different project, it is not working. below is the code:

```
<td><h:outputLabel value="No Polisi:"/></td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{motor.VNOPOL}" id="VNOPOL"/></td>
                         <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="VIDPROSPEK VFRAMENUM VENGINENUM VTHNPROD NKMSERVICE " listener="#{motor.fullInfo}"/>
```

I got an error:

> /index.xhtml @30,146  'valueChange' is not a supported event
>   for HtmlForm. Please specify one of these supported event names:
>   click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove,
>   mouseout, mouseover, mouseup.

What should I implement to show all info after my input in VNOPOL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSF ajax supports only for JSF components, you have not enclosed `<f:ajax>` inside the component

you should change your code as below

```
<td>
   <h:inputText value="#{motor.VNOPOL}" id="VNOPOL">
       <f:ajax event="your event" render="your elements" listener="your listener"/>
   </h:inputText>
</td>
```

Note that the `<f:ajax>` now inside `<h:inputText>`

Comment: this answer is partly correct. Since it is not inside an input, it is added to tge first ancestor element tgat us a jsf tag. In this case, according to the error, an `h:form` which only supports the events mentioned in the error.

Comment: Why this question is voted down? Am I doing something wrong in my question @Kukeltje

Comment: @rashidnk do you know why this question is voted down?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but if I would, the reason would have been 'lack of investigation'. Since the error very clearly states what is wrong

Comment: i see nothing wrong in this question, pls read stackoverflow rules carefully before asking a question